# Can we Store and Retrieve Multiple Images in one SQL column?

Tags: sql-server, winforms, database-design

Hello Everyone I'm new in programming. I am working on small project in my project 
I have 
windows form where user will upload 4 to 6 Images and i want to store these images 
in SQL Database Table After that i want to retrieve these Images regarding one user.

Now my question is how can i store these images in one SQL column without any new row in Database Table?

Is it right way to store and retrieve Images ?

Comment: It would be best to have 1 row for each image in a separate table from the user. Each row can link back to the user table

Comment: Yes, you are right the idea you tell me is easy and simple to retrieve images of users. Thanks

Comment: I search on google but i could not found this type of example How can i design these type of tables Please clarify? @Mike

Answer (score 1):

You store image names in your database, and not images themselves.
Also, store image names of the 4-6 pictures belonging to one customer in one cell and not a column. Try this, hope it works.

Comment: physical paths of images is not suitable. Storage of images is needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to store images rather than paths in the database use a varbinary field.  Once in the database it is easy to use the images in reports (ssrs) of you can extract and use in your application.

There used to be an image datatype but that is being removed. Also consider the size of the image 1MB + and you really should be storing paths.

You will need to import your image and convert to varbinary. Example:

```
MemoryStream ms = newMemoryStream();
pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms,ImageFormat.Jpeg);
byte[] photo_aray = newbyte[ms.Length];
ms.Position = 0;
ms.Read(photo_aray, 0, photo_aray.Length);
```

Here is a link to  a demonstration that should help:  [tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/e628d9/inserting-retrieving-images-from-sql-server-database-without-using-stored-procedures/)